# "http://localhost:8080/jbossws/services" shows 404 but WSDL is published successfull. Why?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss7.x

I do some prototyping for JBoss 7 including a web service. I can start the server and request the WSDL from my browser. So it seems the web service is published successfully.

But:

1. The service does not show up in the Administration Console
2. The URL *http://localhost:8080/jbossws/services* returns a *HTTP Status 404*
3. The server log contains a warning *[org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.resolver.JBossWSResourceResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Cannot resolve resource: cxf* (related?)

Excerpt from the log:

```
15:21:20,623 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-1) Add Service
 id=AccessControlCOM
 address=http://localhost:8080/mymodule/AccessControl
 implementor=mymodule.AccessControlCOM
 invoker=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker
 serviceName={http://mymodule/}AccessControlCOMService
 portName={http://mymodule/}AccessControlPort
 wsdlLocation=null
 mtomEnabled=false
15:21:20,625 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.DefaultEndpointRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) register: jboss.ws:context=mymodule,endpoint=AccessControlCOM
15:21:20,817 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Creating Service {http://mymodule/}AccessControlCOMService from class mymodule.AccessControlCOM
15:21:21,104 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) registering web context: /mymodule2
15:21:21,300 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/mymodule/AccessControl
15:21:21,309 WARN  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.resolver.JBossWSResourceResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Cannot resolve resource: cxf
15:21:21,395 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher] (MSC service thread 1-1) WSDL published to: file:/home/deu/Programme/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/standalone/data/wsdl/mymodule.ear/mymodule.war/AccessControlCOMService.wsdl
15:21:21,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices.service.EndpointService] (MSC service thread 1-8) Starting service jboss.ws.endpoint."mymodule".AccessControlCOM
15:21:21,496 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) registering web context: /com.sysgo.imact.access.com
15:21:21,534 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployed "mymodule.ear"
```

Someone can guess the reason?

BTW: I renamed the *standalone-preview.xml* to *standalone.xml*

Comment: is this issue fixed.?? if yes, can you please post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

afaik there no /jbossws/services in jboss7

do you use wsdl at this address?
 http://localhost:8080/mymodule/AccessControl?wsdl

Comment: Yes, I use that wsdl and it works ... it just don't show up in the administration console.